# Show the decimal value of Char in textbox

Tags: c#, winforms, serial-port

I'm receiving a Byte from FPGA and it appears in textbox4, however, since my output is (ex: 0x03 or 0x07...) what appear in textbox is strange symbols (which I believe is the ASCII representation of 0x03) :
[image: the interface]

so what I want is the output to be just 3(decimal value of 0x03), how can I do it?
I tried alot (see textbox5 of my code) but I couldn't, can you help a beginner? thx.
Note: My FPGA calculate M^e mod G-> 33^5 mod 35 = 3
--the code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form2 : Form
    {


        public Form2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        string RXstring = "";


        private void pictureBox2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            serialPort1.Close();
            Form1 myForm = new Form1();
            this.Close();


        }

        private void groupBox1_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                if (!serialPort1.IsOpen)
                {

                    serialPort1.Open();
                    button3.Enabled = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Port is Open by other party!");

                }


            }
            catch (UnauthorizedAccessException ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }

        private void Form2_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
        {
            serialPort1.Close();
        }

        private void serialPort1_DataReceived(object sender, System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                RXstring = serialPort1.ReadExisting();
                this.Invoke(new EventHandler(displaytext));
            }
            catch (System.TimeoutException)
            {

            }

            }
        private void displaytext(object s, EventArgs e)
        {
            //var a = RXstring[0];
            //var b = RXstring[1];
            //string h = String.Format("{0:X2}", RXstring);
             textBox4.AppendText(RXstring);


        }

        void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Get the strings (text)
            string textM = textBox1.Text;
            string textE = textBox2.Text;
            string textG = textBox3.Text;

            //Assuming you want unsigned numbers, convert to numeric types
            //You might want to put in exception handling for invalid inputs, watch for overflows etc.
            UInt16 bitsX = Convert.ToUInt16(0x1F01);
            UInt16 bitsM = Convert.ToUInt16(textM);
            UInt16 bitsE = Convert.ToUInt16(textE);
            UInt16 bitsG = Convert.ToUInt16(textG);


            /*
             * BitConverter puts the LSB at index 0, so depending on how you need to send the data,
             * you might want to reverse the bytes BitConverter.GetBytes(bitsM).Reverse();
             * or reverse the order you add them to the list
             */
            var byteList = new List<byte>();
            byteList.AddRange(BitConverter.GetBytes(bitsX));
            byteList.AddRange(BitConverter.GetBytes(bitsM));
            byteList.AddRange(BitConverter.GetBytes(bitsE));
            byteList.AddRange(BitConverter.GetBytes(bitsG));

            //Debugging message, uses LINQ 
            string bits = String.Join(" ",byteList.Select(b => b.ToString("X2")));
            MessageBox.Show(bits);


            //write the bytes
            var bitArray = byteList.ToArray();
            serialPort1.Write(bitArray, 0, 8);
            //var x = bitArray[1] + (bitArray[2] << 0) + (bitArray[3] << 0) + (bitArray[4] << 0) + (bitArray[5] << 0) + (bitArray[6] << 0) + (bitArray[7] << 0);

            //string y = String.Format("{0:X2}", x);
            //string y = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bitArray);
            //textBox5.AppendText(y);

        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            textBox1.Text = "";
            textBox2.Text = "";
            textBox3.Text = "";
            textBox4.Text = "";
        }

        private void textBox5_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var value = Convert.ToInt16(textBox4);
            string ss = value.ToString();

            MessageBox.Show(ss.ToString());
            string stringValue = Char.ConvertFromUtf32(value);

            decimal vOut = Convert.ToDecimal(textBox4);
            textBox5.AppendText(vOut.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5PXKMhwKWQRUHVVUi1pVWdmSm8/view?usp=sharing

the error that occur

Comment: Can you check the value of M before the operation that is giving an error, it looks like the M.Substring operation is failing because the length of the string is smaller than the size of substring you are trying to extract

Comment: Well, the exception you're getting is that your string is not long enough. When you call `M.Substring(x, 2)`, `x` specifies the starting point of the substring, and `2` specifies the number of characters to get. If `x` greater than the length of the string - 2, then you will get that exception.

Comment: And that is some crazy code. It's no wonder you don't understand what it's doing.

Comment: In the for loop at some point x+2 becomes greater than the length of string M and hence the error

Comment: Man, this code must be written by a C programmer.  The way the variables are declared (and names are not descriptive) hurts to read.  Of course that makes sense for code that might talk to an FPGA.  Aparantly there are specific characters in the three textboxes that correspond to certain bits and ... I give up.

Comment: @MarwanHarb you dont need to increase the size of the string, you just need to stop doing the substring operation when approach the end of the string, my answer below should do that. Update here if it still causes the issue

Comment: @Shekhar the error have gone my friend, but do you think this code do what I needed in the first place ? thx

Comment: @RufusL what 16 stand for ? in the code ?

Comment: The base of the number being converted (must be 2, 8, 10, or 16): https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c7xhf79k(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @ryanyuyu hello my friend, you know what I want this to do and I belive you can help, what I need to do is to enter a Decimal number into textbox1 , it must then get converted into 16 bits [2 bytes] (ex: 33 -> 0000000000100001) since in FPGA the input pin crossbones to M is 16 bits wide, while for the second number(in textbox2) E it must be 8 bits[1 byte], and a third number (I've not mention it in the code) must be 4 bytes, so what I'll send through serial port is an array consent of seven elements what is the best approach to fellow? thanks man :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have broken up the logic into a few steps:

1. Get the text
2. Parse the text into numbers (its binary)
3. Add the bytes to a list.
4. Covert `List<byte>` to array and send to serial port

I've commented the sections below.  I use [`Convert`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.aspx) and [`BitConverter`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.bitconverter) to help with the conversions.  This code is purposely verbose to help show details.

```
void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Get the strings (text)
    string textM = textBox1.Text;
    string textE = textBox2.Text;
    string textG = textBox3.Text;

    //Assuming you want unsigned numbers, convert to numeric types
    //You might want to put in exception handling for invalid inputs, watch for overflows etc.
    UInt16 bitsM = Convert.ToUInt16(textM);
    byte bitsE = Convert.ToByte(textE);
    UInt32 bitsG = Convert.ToUInt32(textG);


    /*
     * BitConverter puts the LSB at index 0, so depending on how you need to send the data,
     * you might want to reverse the bytes BitConverter.GetBytes(bitsM).Reverse();
     * or reverse the order you add them to the list
     */
    var byteList = new List<byte>();
    byteList.AddRange(BitConverter.GetBytes(bitsM));
    byteList.AddRange(BitConverter.GetBytes(bitsE));
    byteList.AddRange(BitConverter.GetBytes(bitsG));

    //Debugging message, uses LINQ 
    string bits = String.Join(" ", byteList.Select(b => b.ToString("X2")));
    MessageBox.Show(bits);


    //write the bytes
    var bitArray = byteList.ToArray();
    serialPort1.Write(bitArray, 0, 7);
}
```

Comment: thank you very much for your answer, thank you indeed, however I encountered another problem, it seems like my FPGA receives no character from which I send, I can't relate where the FPGA got its characters really, I tried to send and receive an integer and I got the write answers (I used realterm to send and receive at the other end), I'll attach the C-Code for reading from arrays( the one that doesn't work)
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5PXKMhwKWQRSjNGQkVMb3Zrd28/view?usp=sharing
please if you can, give it a look and tell me whether my code is wrong or not.

Comment: @MarwanHarb I wish you the best of luck, but I'm not going to trying to debug something remotely.  That's insanely hard.  Also I'm not actually great in C because of the lack of abstraction.  If you can identify a fairly specific problem please post another question and others can surely help.

Comment: hello my friend, I finally have fixed bugs in my C-code and I'm able to send and receive data the way I want, however I find I bug and I really hope you can help me, when I press send, the program acutely store the inputs then when I press send again it sends the data(I've checked many times), also I wonder if there is a way I can show the output in such form (for example: when the result is 3 and it got send to the textbox, it shows weird digit for which I checked it cosponsored to 0x03 in ASCII table) so I want it to show 3, is that possible, thank you @ryanyuyu

Comment: @MarwanHarb post your new problem as a new question.  That way many people can help you.  Just provide a link to the new question, and I can also look at.  If you need to, you can also put a link to this question for some context in your new question.

Comment: the problem is I can't put a new question for the upcoming six days, so I can only comment on my old questions, I'm really sorry for bothering you, but I'm in great need for help, I forgot that, I have added 2 lines to the code you write, and that might be the problem !
          //  UInt16 bitsX = 0x1F;
            var byteList = new List<byte>();
         //   byteList.AddRange(BitConverter.GetBytes(bitsX).Reverse());

Comment: @MarwanHarb well comments aren't designed for questions and answers.  You should try to [fix your question ban](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255583/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th/255584#255584) first.

Comment: hello my good friend, thank to you I've ended phase 1 of the project and my instructor is happy, yet, in the next phase, I had another problem, can you please help me at this very last question?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29389442/how-to-send-and-receive-1024-bits

Comment: @MarwanHarb ok I'll check it out if I have time.

Answer (score 1):

Your code tries to convert a *hex-string (like: 1234567890ABCDEF)* to byte array. See a simplified version of it

```
string M = "2A";
byte b = Convert.ToByte((M.Substring(0, 2)), 16);
```

which will give you `42` in decimal.

You can do it easily with build-in classes in .NET

```
byte[] data = SoapHexBinary.Parse(M).Value;
```

PS: *SoapHexBinary* is in `System.Runtime.Remoting.Metadata.W3cXsd2001` namespace

Answer (score -2):

In the for loop at some point x+2 becomes greater than the length of string M and hence the error.
To get rid of the it, change the first for loop it to :

```
 for (i = 3; i < 13; i++)
 {
      if(x + 2 <= M.Length)
      {
          data[i + 1] = Convert.ToByte((M.Substring(x, 2)), 16);
          x += 2;
      }
  }
```

*Edit* -
You mention that the input is in form of 1s and 0s which makes it binary, in that case change the above to :

```
Convert.ToByte((M.Substring(x, 2)), 2);
```

---

**Update** as IV4 rightly pointed out  - you are trying to convert binary string to Byte, but the code is meant to convert hex string to byte
Code needs to be modified to work accordingly.

```
 for (i = 3; i < 13; i++)
     {
          if(x + 8 <= M.Length)
          {
              data[i + 1] = Convert.ToByte((M.Substring(x, 8)), 2);
              x += 8;
          }
      }
```

Comment: **a)** it is still not correct. Either `Convert.ToByte((M.Substring(x, 2)), 16)` or  `Convert.ToByte((M.Substring(x, 8)), 2)` **b)** My guess, *binary input* is only a assumption of OP(just because he doesn't understand the code). The code in question is clearly tries to convert hex string to byte array as @EZI noted.

Comment: @I4V silly me :( copy paste error . I know ,it probably a futile effort here, but the OP was provided the code by somebody claiming it would work , which it clearly doesn't, so we can only guess whether to follow what the code is trying to do and what the OP is. Since EZI answered correcting the code, I went with trying to solve what the OP mentioned in his text.

Comment: @I4V hello, I would like to thank your for taking time to answer my question, so what you are saying this code convert hex to byte ? what I need to do is to enter a Decimal number into textbox1 , it must then get converted into 16 bits [2 bytes] (ex: 33 -> 0000000000100001) since in FPGA the input pin crossbones to M is 16 bits wide, while for the second number E it must be 8 bits[1 byte], and a third number (I've not mention it in the code) must be 4 bytes, so what I'll send through serial port is an array consent of seven elements what is the best approach to fellow? thanks man :)