# How to send and receive 1024 Bits?

Tags: c#

I'm designing an interface using C# windows Forms and I want to send and receive 1024 bits using serial port, the number I'm sending is in the hex-form, so what I did was the next:

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int i;
    int a = 0;
    byte[] mychar;
    mychar = new byte[128];
    string M = textBox1.Text;

    for (i = 0; i < 127; i++ )
    {
        mychar[i] = Convert.ToByte((M.Substring(a,2)),16);
        a += 2;
    }
    serialPort1.Write(mychar,0,127);
}
```

and to check if the data is correct or not, I shorted out both the transmitter and receiver so I can see what I send from textbox1 to be shown in textbox5, the problem is the textbox is shown the output as ASCII, and I couldn't tell how to convert it to Hex form ,(see my attempt as commented bellow):

```
private void displaytext(object s, EventArgs e)
{
    textBox5.Clear();
    textBox5.AppendText(RXstring);
    //int value = Convert.ToInt32(RXstring, 16);
    //string stringValue = Char.ConvertFromUtf32(value);
    //textBox4.AppendText(stringValue);
}
```

so to **summarize my problems**:
1- Is the code to send data is correct?
2- How can I force the textbox to show the output as Hex?

thank you very much.

**UPDATE** this is my full code, maybe then you understand my problem :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form3 : Form
    {
        public Form3()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        string RXstring = "";
        private void serialPort1_DataReceived(object sender, System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                RXstring = serialPort1.ReadExisting();
                this.Invoke(new EventHandler(displaytext));
            }
            catch (System.TimeoutException)
            {

            }
        }
            private void displaytext(object s, EventArgs e)
        {

            textBox5.Clear();
             textBox5.AppendText(RXstring);
             //int value = Convert.ToInt32(RXstring, 16);
             //string stringValue = Char.ConvertFromUtf32(value);
             //textBox4.AppendText(stringValue);
        }

            private void pictureBox2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                serialPort1.Close();
                Form1 myForm = new Form1();
                this.Close();
            }

            private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                try
                {
                    if (!serialPort1.IsOpen)
                    {

                        serialPort1.Open();
                        button1.Enabled = false;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Port is Open by other party!");

                    }


                }
                catch (UnauthorizedAccessException ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                }
            }

            private void Form3_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
            {
                serialPort1.Close();
            }

            private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                textBox1.Text = "0";
                textBox2.Text = "0";
                textBox3.Text = "0";
                textBox4.Text = "0";
                textBox5.Text = "";
            }

            private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                int i;
                int a=0;
                byte[] mychar;
                mychar = new byte[128];
                string M = textBox1.Text;

                for (i = 0; i < 127; i++ ) {
                mychar[i] = Convert.ToByte((M.Substring(a,2)),16);
                a += 2;
                }
                serialPort1.Write(mychar,0,127);
            }

        }
    }
```

when I send data from textbox1 I want to be shown exactly as I send it in textbox5, can you help me in that ?
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5PXKMhwKWQRREtuMXBaZDA1LUU/view?usp=sharing

Comment: What is *C# windows Forums*? :)

Comment: @BinkanSalaryman Forms*, obviously.

Comment: @BinkanSalaryman I am pretty sure its WPF

Comment: You can't force a textbox to show text as anything else than text. But you can of course do the opposite and convert each byte in the buffer to hex with format string `02X` for example.

Comment: as someone who has to cope with code like this from time to time: *the very first thing* I want you to do is re**name** your controls - *please*

Comment: You'll receive bytes, you have to convert them to hex again.  Simple to do with BitConverter.ToString(byte[]) method.

Comment: Are we talking ASCII(I guess), Unicode, ... ?

Comment: The `Convert.ToByte((M.Substring(a,2)),16)` indicates that he has a textbox with binary data in hexadecimal representation already. Thus he does not need to consider encoding in this step.

Comment: Use `FromHexString` in `button2_Click` and `ToHexString` in `displaytext` (see my answer for the `From`/`ToHexString` methods)

Comment: Can you include what the `RXstring` looks like?  It would be helpful to know what kind of string we need to format.

Comment: @ryanyuyu what I send is this hex number :

2489108B0B6AF86BED9E44C2336442D5E227DBA55EF8E26A7E437194119077F003B9C027852BB3126C99C16D5F1057BC8361DCB26A5B2DB4229DB3DE5BD979B2E597D1916D7BBC92746FC07595C76B44B39A476A65C86F086DC9283CA6D1EEFC14915982F9C4CED5F62A9FF3BE24218A99357B5B65C3B10AEB367E911EB9E21

so , I should see the same at the output to confirm my answer (since I shorted out both the transmitter and receiver pins.

Comment: @MarwanHarb ok.  How about the result of a single `serialPort1.ReadExisting()`?  Is that a 32-bit number?

Comment: @ryanyuyu as far I understand and examined this function, a single output is 8 bit long

Answer (score 0):

This [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) shows how to convert between `byte`s and hexadecimal `string`s:

```
class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        byte[] bytes = FromHexString("0123456789ABCEF");
        string text = ToHexString(bytes);
        Console.Write(text);
        Console.ReadKey(true);
    }

    static byte[] FromHexString(string hexString) {
        byte[] result;
        //determine length and handle case of uneven digit count
        int length = hexString.Length / 2;
        bool even = length * 2 == hexString.Length;
        if(!even) {
            length++;
        }
        //allocate memory
        result = new byte[length];

        int offset;
        if(even) {
            offset = 0;
        } else {
            //convert first digit, if digit count is uneven 
            result[0] = Convert.ToByte(hexString[0].ToString(), 16);
            offset = 1;
        }
        for(int i = offset; i < result.Length; i++) {
            //convert digit to byte
            result[i] = Convert.ToByte((hexString.Substring(i * 2 - offset, 2)), 16);
        }
        return result;
    }

    static string ToHexString(byte[] bytes, bool upperCase = true) {
        string format = upperCase ? "X" : "x";
        //initialize result with double capacity as a byte in hex notation occupies 2 chars
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder(bytes.Length * 2);
        foreach(var @byte in bytes) {
            result.Append(@byte.ToString(format));
        }
        return result.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, I'm beginner so I 'm not sure if this is my problem solution, what my problem is what ever I receive in my textbox5 is converted to its ASCII representation (which as far I know this is standard for textbox), my instructor told there is some conversions which will do the job, however, I couldn't find any, can you please help at this problem? thanks alot.

Comment: What do you receive in your `textbox5`? Is it a `string`? I don't know your environment, but if conversion methods already exist as you wrote, you should ask your instructor again where to find it.

Comment: hello, I've posted my full code + how the interface looks like, can you give a look, I would be very thankful

Comment: From the code I can't tell what `serialPort1.ReadExisting()` does. If it returns a string, I should work fine with `AppendText` of your control. Beside that, I never had to deal with serial ports in programming...

Answer (score 0):

I just added the following to the code :

```
string hex = "";
             foreach (char c in RXstring)
             {
                 int tmp = c;
                 hex += String.Format("{0:X2}", (uint)System.Convert.ToUInt32(tmp.ToString()));
             }
             textBox5.AppendText(hex);
```

thank you any way :)